# bootrec.exe as a bootable program for USB

Tags: windows-7, boot

The damaged boot sector of Windows is not a new story to be told. Often we are required to repair the boot sector using the installation disc.

Is there any alternative other than using the Installation disc for this purpose? Like may be we can create a bootable disk containing bootrec.exe and launch it through a USB drive to repair it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by creating a USB Windows repair disk and running `chkdsk` from a Command Prompt. If `bootrec.exe` is not a default file you could add it to the USB. The link below has a good step-by-step guide to creating the bootable USB:

http://mintywhite.com/windows-7/7maintenance/windows-wont-load-system-repair-disc-fix-pc/